# El elemento div no se puede anidar dentro del elemento ul

Tags: html, css

Descargué una plantilla en boostrap 4.
Pero al colocarlo en el editor de texto del Visual Studio, me dice la siguiente advertencia:

> El elemento div no se puede anidar dentro del elemento ul

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan en la foto, el div está marcado con linea verde y el tag `<li>`.

Hasta ahora se ve todo bien en los navegadores, pero en el futuro, con las actualizaciones de los navegadores, podría verse mal.

La plantilla de base la descargué de [esta página](http://pratikborsadiya.in/vali-admin/dashboard.html)

Answer (score 2):

Si leemos al respecto de las *listas desordenadas `ul`* en [Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element), posee las siguientes características:

- Sus nodos hijos directos se representan por medio de las etiquetas `li`
- Representa una lista de valores desordenada
- Aún con movimientos de posición de los elementos internos, el significado no se pierde

Por otro lado si leemos de esto mismo en la [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/ul.html) nos da aspectos interesantes para analizar:

- Puede tener como hijos directos 0 o N elementos `li`
- Puede tener pero como *elementos padre* a los `div`
- Sus elementos internos se representan por las etiquetas `li`

Entonces

Dado eso no se ve muy práctico que un grupo de `li` estén dentro de un `div` el cual de por si es un elemento sin valor semántico y aunque en teoría el acomodo es factible, pues tanto un `ul` como un `div` son [elementos en bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), no parece ser la opción mas viable o válida.

Aportaciones se pueden dar, pero debes considerar que:

- Es un diseño prehecho el que tratas de modificar
- Conforme mas modifiques el diseño, deberás observar que elementos de la interfaz se pierden y como deberás reacomodarlos
- Puede que tengas que incluso construir algo propio si a detalles como estos si planeas darle atención.